# Excel vlookup not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using a Mac.

I have 3 categories of ZIP Codes, Zone 1, Zone 2 and Zone 3. I have a list of ZIP Codes and I need to see easily if a zip code is zone 1, 2 or 3.

Column E holds my ZIP Code.  Column F has my zone listing, with value 1, 2 or 3.

Sheet 2 holds my ZIP Code list, but it is massive. One is 514 rows. I am currently doing this manually and it's taking forever.

My Vlookup formula is shown in the image, and gives me an error.

Realistically, it would be great if it returned a value of 1, 2 or 3. However if it just returned anything and I had to go through each column of ZIP Codes, even that would be great.

[image: https://ibb.co/6DHfhN3]

Comment: Welcome.  Can you please post a screenshot of examples you are talking about along with your VLOOKUP which is returning an error? It makes it easier than trying to visualise and piece together your description of what you have.

Comment: I attached that, hope it's helpful

Comment: "..my zone listening" did you mean 'listing'?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  What does sheet2 look like?  Where is the source data you want to look up?  Where is the destination you want to fill in?  Is Q:S your lookup table where you see what ZIPs are in what zones, or is that the table you're trying to build based on what's in the data?

Comment: The screenshot is really hard to see & I would suggest including the VLOOKUP formula in text, but you also do need to give a hint about Sheet 2 data.  However, I see a reference to "X1" where there should be a column number reference instead - the column number from the reference range - and you also don't specify -what- error.  If VLOOKUP doesn't find a match, it normally will show an "error".

Comment: @Debra , just FYI, images are embedded in a clickable form, so you can right-click an image and open it full size in another tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in F2.. put :

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(E2,H:H,0)>1,1,""),"")&IFERROR(IF(MATCH(E2,I:I,0)>1,2,""),"")&IFERROR(IF(MATCH(E2,J:J,0)>1,3,""),"")
```

& drag downwards.

Idea : check if match found, print zone number, else print blank. concatenate all.

catch : if there is a postcode is repeated in more than 1 zone, It'll print both zone.

Hope it helps.  ( :

Comment: You are my hero sir....